# How to write Cookie class unit test in php

Tags: php, unit-testing, cookies

how to write unit test for the class code?
also i am getting this error when i wrote test
"session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent"

```
class Cookie
{
    function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
    }
    public static function isthere($name)
    {
        return (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function get($name)
    {
        return $_COOKIE[$name];
    }

    public static function create($name,$valu,$time)
    {
        if(setcookie($name,$valu,time() + $time,'/')){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function delete($name)
    {
        self::create($name,'',time()-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is generated when you echo something before you execute ```session_start()```, for the unit test, what have you tried before?

Comment: Why do you have `session_start()` in your cookie class? Sessions and cookies are not the same thing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson understand, how can I write unit test for cookie and session class?

Comment: I would suggest that you do some research. There are plenty of guides/examples out there.